# OkHttp Http2 Audio stream, Can I control sent bytes?

Tags: android, okhttp, http2

I am trying to send audio stream using OkHttp following example presented [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/PostStreamingWithPipe.java),
But the problem is if I am using pipe I have no control over how bytes are sent to the server, and this is causing some interruption in the audio because server is sensitive to the bytes flow.

Listening to the port I saw that using Pipe I send wrong chunk sizes
Expected:

4,
626,
4,
1255,
4,
1091,

Reality:
1460,
1460,
1460,
2109,
1460

Is there a way to manipulate how data is sent using `PipeBody`? tried to add `Thread.sleep` and `flush()` between `sink.write(data)` but didn't see any changes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to flush more often in the code that accepts pipe data and sends it on the HTTP request.

Replace this:

```
@Override public void writeTo(BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
  sink.writeAll(pipe.source());
}
```

With this:

```
@Override public void writeTo(BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
  sink.writeAllFrequentFlush(pipe.source());
}
```

Then write a function that flushes at every opportunity. This one is derived from the Okio writeAll function.

```
fun BufferedSink.writeAllFrequentFlush(source: Source): Long {
  var totalBytesRead = 0L
  while (true) {
    val readCount: Long = source.read(buffer, 8192L)
    if (readCount == -1L) break
    totalBytesRead += readCount
    emit()
  }
  return totalBytesRead
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it seems to make no difference in my case, resulted in more or less same chunk sizes as before: 162, 6636, 1460, 6605,1460, 6549,1460

Comment: Try flushing frequently on the producing side?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but sadly it is not possible.

Comment: Why not? It looks like that's your problem!

Comment: The 2 examples of data (expected and reality) are from the same producing side implementation, only difference is that in "expected" case was used socket and in "reality" side was used OkHttp with pipe, basicaly I am getting good data, but it does not getting writted correctly.